# How to align images a the bottom

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to align images at the bottom of the screen in the format img1 str  img2 |img3 ,the issue i am facing is if the str is small the images are getting shifted left ,else the images moves right based on the string length.I want to keep the images always at the right corner ,how to do it ?

```
VerticalFieldManager test = new VerticalFieldManager();

    HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                FIELD_BOTTOM | Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
            public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x316AC5);
                graphics.clear();
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
        };

        Bitmap fadeBitmap = Bitmap
                .getBitmapResource("icon_tz_faded_316AC5_35x39.png");
        Bitmap clockBitmap = Bitmap
                .getBitmapResource("icon_date_picker_white_316AC5_35x39.png");
        Bitmap tzBitmap = Bitmap
                .getBitmapResource("icon_tz_white_316AC5_35x39.png");

        final ImageButtonField unfocus = new ImageButtonField("",
                Field.FOCUSABLE | FIELD_LEFT, "icon_tz_faded_316AC5_35x39.png",
                "icon_tz_faded_316AC5_35x39.png", 0xFFFFFF);

        final ImageButtonField bitmapField = new ImageButtonField("",
                Field.FOCUSABLE | ImageButtonField.FIELD_RIGHT,
                "icon_date_picker_white_316AC5_35x39.png",
                "icon_date_picker_selected_35x39.png", 0xFFFFFF);

        final ImageButtonField bitmapField1 = new ImageButtonField("",
                Field.FOCUSABLE | ImageButtonField.FIELD_RIGHT,
                "icon_tz_white_316AC5_35x39.png", "icon_tz_selected_35x39.png",
                0xFFFFFF);

        int margin = ((Display.getWidth() - (fadeBitmap.getWidth()
                + clockBitmap.getWidth() + tzBitmap.getWidth() + timezoneTitle
                .getWidth())) / 4);

        unfocus.setMargin(0, 3, 0, 0);
        timezoneTitle.setMargin(0, 120, 0, 0);
        bitmapField1.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);

        horizontalFieldManager.add(unfocus);
        horizontalFieldManager.add(timezoneTitle);
        horizontalFieldManager.add(bitmapField);
    horizontalFieldManager.add(bitmapField1);
            test.add(horizontalFieldManager);
```

Comment: Don't replicate your own question. You can update your old question always, e.g. you can update the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10928959/431639. Also check this, `What if I don’t get a good answer?`, http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Create another horizontal field and add images to this field, then use setPadding(top,left,bottom,right) to arrange the images in order.